# SoapClient PHP code without WSDL from example CURL request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to call a SOAP API using PHP and have been given the following example CURL call:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://soapurl.test/mysoapcall'
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml'
--header 'client-id: <<your client id>>'
--header 'client-secret: <<your client secret>>'
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <<token>>'
--data-raw '<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header></env:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns0:getReturnedValues xmlns:ns0="https://soapurl.test/anotherurl1" xmlns:ns1="https://soapurl.test/anotherurl2">
            <ns0:var1>100</ns0:var1>
            <ns0:var2>XXX</ns0:var2>
        </ns0:getReturnedValues>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>'
```

I can successfully call the above via Postman, but when I am writing the PHP code using SoapClient, I keep getting "One or more required API parameters are missing in the API request."

I know that I must have something wrong with how I am defining the SOAP headers or how I am defining the uri, but I can't work out what it is.

Here is my PHP code:

```php
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "https://soapurl.test/mysoapcall",
                                     'uri'      => "https://soapurl.test/anotherurl1");

$ns = 'https://soapurl.test/anotherurl1';

$headers = array();

$headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns, 
                            'client-id',
                            'my_client_id');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns, 
                            'client-secret',
                            'my_client_secret');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns, 
                            'Authorization',
                            'Bearer my_bearer_token');

$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

$client->__soapCall("getReturnedValues", array('var1'=>'100', 'var2' => 'XXX'));
$client->__soapCall("getReturnedValues", [
   new \SoapParam('100', 'var1'),
   new \SoapParam('XXX', 'var2')
]);
```

My PHP code generates the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:ns1="https://soapurl.test/anotherurl1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:getReturnedValues env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
         <var1 xsi:type="xsd:string">100</var1>
         <var2 xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</var2>
      </ns1:getReturnedValues>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Which is obviously not the same as the example I was supplied with.

I'm new to SOAP, so please can someone advise on what I am doing wrong?  Many thanks

Comment: At a quick glance `var1` and `var2` are missing their namespaces which are supposed to be bound to a variable with value `https://soapurl.test/anotherurl1`. I think you can use [`SoapVar`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php) instead of SoapParam to do that.